# Where to find report about ECC DDR single bit failure rates on Windows?

Tags: memory, ecc, warning

We have a windows server 2012 with ECC DDR3 installed.  Recently the Dell admin software that came with it started reporting single-bit correction warnings on one of the modules:

[image: Memory]

[image: Memory Detail]

My question is, is there any equivalent information recorded in event viewer?  I could not find anything after searching for the text phrase "memory" under the System, Hardware events, and Administrative Event views.  Is it generally required to install some special software from the Memory Mfg or builder (Dell) to be able to monitor ECC Warnings (high single bit failure rate)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install **[Dell OpenManage Server Administrator](http://www.dell.com/support/contents/ca/en/cabsdt1/article/Product-Support/Self-support-Knowledgebase/enterprise-resource-center/SystemsManagement/OMSA)** from Dell

The information will be logged into the Hardware tab after.

That will install too a small webpage that will show the required information.

At the same time it will add a SMNP service that you can send request to get the information.

Comment: That is where the screenshots came from.  The question is whether there is a generic Windows way to do it.  Say it wasn't a Dell system.

Comment: @crokusek no, but major brand all got tool like that.